# Inactive/greyed out faces (solved)

Tags: edit-mode, faces

I'm using Blender 3 and after making a race track I've noticed that some of the faces on my kerbs are greyed out or inactive - but only in X-ray mode (for example selected faces in screenshot1). They are displayed normally in all other modes (screenshot 2).

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

If I export the track and import it into Unity, the greyed out parts are missing. I haven't found an option to enable/disable faces. Also no luck on google - I'm new to Blender and probably don't search for the correct terms.

I really appreciate the help, thank you in advance!

Kind regards, Alex

Edit: moonboots' answer helped. Select faces, press Shift+N and check "inside" in the area that pops up in bottom left corner.

Comment: maybe their normal is inverted? Select all in Edit mode and press Shift N to see if that fixes the problem

Comment: if moonboots answer doesn't help, pls provide blend file

Comment: @moonboots Thank you, that helped!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal of these faces are probably inverted. Select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals.